# How to combine multiple columns into one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Based on the Google Form input I have the following data collected from the user

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name  |  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| name1 |        |        |    1   |
| name2 |   3    |        |        |
| name3 |        |   2    |        |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

which only one of the Col1, Col2 or Col3 will contain value

What I want is to created a view like this

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  |  Col   |
+-------+--------+
| name1 |    1   |
| name3 |    2   |
| name2 |    3   |
+-------+--------+
```

The SQL command should not only merge Col1, Col2 and Col3 but also sort the new Col based on it value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
select name, coalesce(col1, col2, col3) as col
from t
order by col;
```

Comment: How come this works? Google Sheet's SQL does not support coalesce().

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method below (I'-'I's answer is good but a little overcomplicated) given the particularities of your data

```
=sort(arrayformula({H1:H6, I1:I6 + J1:J6 + K1:K6}), 2, true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sheets doesn't support full sql.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT({A2:A4,MMULT(--B2:D4,TRANSPOSE(B2:D2^0))},2,1))
```